# Postpone signalR long polling request

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, websocket, signalr

I am using Angular and signalR library for streaming data from the .NET core backend.

There is a couple streaming type and I tried 2 of them:

1. web socket
2. long polling

Streaming works perfect, and backend send me a lot of data which I put into the queue and process on the frontend side. The problem is that after some time queue is full and I need to escape(throw) data which backend send to me. At that moment I want to inform backend that I am busy and it can get a break for a bit (I do not want backend to spend resource to send me data which I cannot process). If I dispose of the streaming and start again it is too slow, so I need something much faster.

I noticed that when doing the long polling frontend sends request to the backend  only when frontend is not busy, but I do not know how to say that frontend is busy and postopone request.

This is my hub connection and streaming method on the frontend side:

```
 this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.href + '/api/hub/stremingMethod', HttpTransportType.LongPolling)
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();

private startStreaming(streamingId: number): signalR.ISubscription<DataModel> {
    return this.hubConnection.stream<DataModel>('StremingMethod', streamingId).subscribe({
      next: streamingData=> {
        this.addToQueue(streamingData);
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log('complete');
      },
      error: error => {
        console.log('complete');

      }
    });
  }
```

My question is how I can postpone frontend to send request to the server when I want that ? 
Could I have that kind of control in signalR. Currently I am using long polling I can use web socket also.